# How to capitalize every word in excel cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have about 15k rows which each has 3 column similar to following structure.

> ID Title Description
>   0 A short title Some long description about this column

I want to capitalize every single word in `Title` column so it will appear as:
`A Short Title`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=PROPER(B2)
```

The formula can capitalize every 1st character of every word in a string.

EDIT: If you want to do that manually, copy the formula across the column to do that.
You can goto the cell containing formula. On the bottom right corner, you will see a + sign when you hover over the cell - double click the bottom right corner when you see that.

This will copy the formula to the rows underneath the current one, till it finds that there is data in the column preceding it.

EDIT2: Using code

```
Option Explicit
Sub ChangeAllCellsInThisColumnToProperCase(ByVal StartCell As Range)
Dim LastCell As Range
Set LastCell = StartCell.End(xlDown)

Dim data
Dim RangeToCover As Range

Set RangeToCover = Range(StartCell.Address & ":" & LastCell.Address)
data = RangeToCover.Value

Dim CountOfCells As Long
CountOfCells = RangeToCover.Cells.Count

Dim Counter, element
For Counter = 1 To CountOfCells
    element = data(Counter, 1)
    element = WorksheetFunction.Proper(element)
    data(Counter, 1) = element
Next

Range(StartCell.Address & ":" & LastCell.Address).Value = data
End Sub
```

EDIT3: Doing it manually (after @mehow's comment)
- Type in the formula in another empty column (say column F) that does a proper case on B2.
- Copy the formula, Select rest of the cells where you want this formula to be applied.
- Paste Special -> Formulas
- Copy the column contents of F
- Goto column B's first cell, Do a Paste Special -> Values.

Comment: Thanks that's it. However can you explain how to apply that to all my rows ?

Comment: Ahh just found it. Thank you once again.

Comment: well since there are values in column B , he cannot use this formula on the actual column because it would erase his values if he tried to insert it. so, i dont understand why this is the best answer lol

Comment: @mehow: You are right. I don't know what made OP choose this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To run this quickly on a single column you could use a variant array

For column B:

```
Sub QuickUpdate()
Dim X()
Dim lngRow As Long
X = Range([b1], Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    X(lngRow, 1) = Application.Proper(X(lngRow, 1))
Next lngRow
[B1].Resize(UBound(X, 1), UBound(X, 2)).Value2 = X
End Sub
```